# Return downloaded file path with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, download

I use the download npm module to download a file.

But I need the get the downloaded file path to launch the installation.

```
// Dependencies.
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request'),
    download = require('download')
    fs = require('fs');

// Download and install latest Chromium build.
function getChromium() {

    request('http://chromium.woolyss.com/download/', function (err, res, html) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var link = $('#p-windows > div > p:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(13) > a').attr('href');
        download(link, 'apps', { extract: false });
        // What should I do now?
    });

}

getChromium();
```

Is it possible? How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [Usage section of the documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/download) it looks like you can specify both a download link and local filename in the first parameter, like this:

```
download({ url: link, name: 'chromium.zip' }, 'apps', { extract: false });
```

That will save the bundle to `'apps/chromium.zip'`.

Comment: I don't want to specify a file name.
I want to get the filepath of the downloaded file.
In this example: **apps/mini_installer.exe**.
In fact, it is to create a function that downloads and returns the file path.